# Camera keeps stopping, when I try to take a photo ( Android Studio )

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to take a photo by calling the camera app. I followed [this tutorial about the camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java)

My code is this:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately my app crashes when `takePhoto` is called, and I get this error:

```
Camera keeps stopping
```

If I manually start the camera app, it works. I can take pictures with the virtual camera.
I use the emulator.
Logcat is set to verbose, but there are no errors there.

---

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <application>...</application>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

---

This is the logcat output:

```
2020-08-04 09:21:41.604 10377-10377/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10377
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{e9301ed 10377:com.example.myapplication/u0a134} (pid=10377, uid=10134) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3851)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1705)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.takePhoto(MainActivity.java:46)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:760)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:583)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1288)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:514)
```

Comment: You should add your `onActivityResult()` method code with your question. And also make sure you take user permission before open camera from your app.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: @blackapps I still get this error

Comment: Put that line in the manifest please. Please post the relevant lines from the logcat. If your app crashes there should be info there.

Comment: Install yet another camera app.

Comment: @blackapps I added the logcat output

Comment: `Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE .... ` That looks as if indeed your camera permission fails. You still did not add it to your manifest i see. I asked you to do that. Also you did not react on the suggestion to install more camera apps.

Comment: `if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` Try without that check. Just start your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask the user permission for accessing the device's camera before you launch that intent.

So the steps goes like this

1. Check if your app has permission to access camera, if so then launch intent
2. if you don't have permission, then at run time request permission, like shown in code below
3. On permission result, just launch your intent.

An example of how to ask for camera permission

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (checkPermission()) {
        //main logic or main code

       // . write your main code to execute, It will execute if the permission is already given.

        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // main logic
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermission();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
}
```